# Apache Ignite cache heap space increases without any activity

Tags: java, heap-memory, ignite

We have been using Ignite 2.11 and have observed that sporadically the heap space used by all the caches can increase by a factor of 2 or 3 across all caches on both server and client nodes (in the case of near caches) without any additional entries being added across ANY of the caches.

Is this behavior normal and or is there a way to prevent it?

The added memory footprint of the client node is causing our application to got out of memory.

Before:

```
Cache 'ENTRIES_CACHE(@c8)':
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name(@)                         | ENTRIES_CACHE(@c8) |
| Total entries (Heap / Off-heap) | 21 (14 / 7)                |
| Nodes                           | 2                          |
| Total size Min/Avg/Max          | 7 / 10.50 / 14             |
|   Heap size Min/Avg/Max         | 7 / 7.00 / 7               |
|   Off-heap size Min/Avg/Max     | 0 / 3.50 / 7               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

Nodes for: ENTRIES_CACHE(@c8)
+================================================================================================================+
|     Node ID8(@), IP      | CPUs | Heap Used | CPU Load |   Up Time    | Size (Primary / Backup)  | Hi/Mi/Rd/Wr |
+================================================================================================================+
| 9C82B7D0(@n1), 127.0.0.1 | 16   | 22.86 %   | 0.23 %   | 04:31:12.703 | Total: 7 (7 / 0)         | Hi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 7 (7 / <n/a>)    | Mi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 0 (0 / 0)    | Rd: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: 0     | Wr: 0       |
+--------------------------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------------------+-------------+
| 7116937A(@n0), 127.0.0.1 | 1    | 18.70 %   | 5.33 %   | 23:01:35.501 | Total: 14 (14 / 0)       | Hi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 7 (7 / <n/a>)    | Mi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 7 (7 / 0)    | Rd: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: <n/a> | Wr: 0       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After:

```
Cache 'ENTRIES_CACHE(@c8)':
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name(@)                         | ENTRIES_CACHE(@c8) |
| Total entries (Heap / Off-heap) | 21 (14 / 7)                |
| Nodes                           | 2                          |
| Total size Min/Avg/Max          | 7 / 10.50 / 14             |
|   Heap size Min/Avg/Max         | 7 / 7.00 / 7               |
|   Off-heap size Min/Avg/Max     | 0 / 3.50 / 7               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

Nodes for: ENTRIES_CACHE(@c8)
+================================================================================================================+
|     Node ID8(@), IP      | CPUs | Heap Used | CPU Load |   Up Time    | Size (Primary / Backup)  | Hi/Mi/Rd/Wr |
+================================================================================================================+
| 9C82B7D0(@n1), 127.0.0.1 | 16   | 30.79 %   | 14.73 %  | 04:36:30.703 | Total: 7 (7 / 0)         | Hi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 7 (7 / <n/a>)    | Mi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 0 (0 / 0)    | Rd: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: 0     | Wr: 0       |
+--------------------------+------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------------------+-------------+
| 7116937A(@n0), 127.0.0.1 | 1    | 31.67 %   | 58.67 %  | 23:06:54.534 | Total: 14 (14 / 0)       | Hi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Heap: 7 (7 / <n/a>)    | Mi: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap: 7 (7 / 0)    | Rd: 0       |
|                          |      |           |          |              |   Off-Heap Memory: <n/a> | Wr: 0       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use jmap to dump memory, and use MAT to dig if there was something like memory leak, i have met such issue when use Apache Ignite ContinuousQuery, especially when some node of the cluster restart, will cause memory leak.

Comment: We have done that but have not see a memory leak.  We are not running any ContinuousQuerys, just using put and get operations.